# How to print US-ASCII - Codepage 20127 characters in a non-English window setting

Tags: c, visual-studio

My class requires `US-ASCII - Codepage 20127` or `Unicode (UTF-8 without signature) - Codepage 65001` characters to be used on all assignments. However, my computer is run in a non-English Windows 10 for work purposes.

I need to, `printf("Use \\n to cause a newline; use \\t to cause a tab.");`
so that `\n to cause a newline; use \t to cause a tab`, will be displayed.

But since my computer settings are incompatible with ASCII code, it doesn't print `\` like it can here. It only prints the character on the button (which looks like `W`) between backspace button and enter button on both Visual Studio (C) and output window (the black window that pops up after debugging).

[image: my actual coding for this project]

What do I need to do to fix this?

I have tried, 
`Tools->Options...->Environment->Documents` and unchecked the `"Save documents as Unicode when data cannot be saved in codepage"` checkbox.

I tried the `save with encoding` option where I tried both `US-ASCII - Codepage 20127` and `Unicode (UTF-8 without signature) - Codepage 65001`. My computer still prints the `W`, not `\`.

My coding:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   printf("Use \\n to cause a newline; use \\t to cause a tab.\n");
   return 0;
}
```

This ouputs `Wn to cause a newline; use Wt to cause a tab.`, where `W` is the character on the button between backspace button and enter button.

[image: Keyboard pic]

Comment: @JonnyHenly no, you don't, because this is not a UTF issue, since the strings in question do not contain any non-ASCII characters in them, so they will be output the same regardless of charset used.

Comment: @SKwon "*But since my computer settings are incompatible with ASCII code*" - just about *EVERY* charset/codepage is compatible with ASCII. Most charsets begin with ASCII characters, and define them with the same byte/numeric values for cross-compatibility. The '\' character is an *escape code* in C++ literals, where '\\' is *supposed* to display as a single '\' in the command terminal, because there is only 1 '\' char in the string's memory at runtime. I see no way that a '\' char (0x5C) could be output as 'W' (0x57) in any charset. Which exact charset/codepage is your system actually using?

Comment: @SKwon Please show a pic of your keyboard, and a screenshot of your actual output. The "character on the button between backspace button and enter button" on most keyboards IS the '\' character, not the `W` character. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdE6y.jpg

Comment: @RemyLebeau you're right about it not being a UTF issue. On another note, OP isn't saying that `\ ` char (0x5C) is being output as `W` (0x57), they're saying that `\ ` is being displayed as a character that looks like `W`.

Comment: @JonnyHenly the only way I could see that happening is if the terminal window (and Visual Studio, too) is using a font that renders char 0x5C as `W` instead of as '\' like it should be.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I had the same thought, but charset rather than font. Font definitely makes more sense. Especially since OP says their browser renders `\ ` correctly and not as the character that looks like `W`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau My computer uses 949 ANSI/OEM.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Here are the pictures of my coding and keyboard. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBXY9.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvRLc.jpg

Comment: @S.Kwon is there a `\ ` character anywhere on your keyboard? A quick workaround is to find the Character Map application, which comes with Windows, and look for the `\ ` character. Then use Character Map to insert backslashes. Not the ideal solution, but it is a quick workaround.

Comment: Are you sure it's a W? https://superuser.com/questions/1167662/why-is-windows-10-displaying-as-%C2%A5-on-the-command-line

Comment: It is not a W, (he said it looks like a W), it is a Won mark, same thing in Japan, the \ button prints a Yen mark. ( The weird thing is, that Yen + t , Yen +n, etc. in some situations will print the yen mark and other situations will work as a backslash)

Comment: On my Japanese keyboard, the original backslash can be found on the key left of the right side shift key

Comment: @SKwon In that case, if you type a `￦` then that is what you are going to get (make sure to save the code file as UTF8, since `￦` does not exist in ASCII). If you want an `\ ` char, that is what you need to type instead. If your keyboard does not have a `\ ` key, there are alternatives (such as using [trigraphs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative) - the trigraph for `\ ` is `??/`, eg `"Use ??/n to cause ..."`).

Answer (score 1):

It's a font problem.  On my US Windows system if I type `chcp 949` it forces the font to "MS Gothic", which displays a different character for backslash:

Before:

[image: C:\Users with backslash]

After:

[image: C:\Users with Yen]

If you cut-and-paste that text into a program like Notepad using a different font like Consolas, the slash will reappear.  The character on the screen is the correct ASCII character...the font is just displaying it with an alternate symbol.

I had trouble getting the console to switch fonts.  Most selections I had in Windows 10 switched back to MS Gothic, but the SimSun fonts would display Korean and the backslash correctly.  I have a Chinese IME installed instead of Korean, so your console font selections may vary.

Comment: Press Alt+Space, Properties, Font tab.  Anything else than MS Gothic produces a backslash.

Comment: @HansPassant I know how to change the font.  Try it yourself.  It switched back to MS Gothic as long as the code page was 949, at least on Windows 10.

Comment: Yes, I did try it before I commented.  Win10.  You have to use chcp first.

Comment: @HansPassant It looks like only certain fonts switch back.  KaiTi and FanSong selections are ignored.  Sometimes Consolas shows up and sometimes not and it switched back as well.  Buggy font selection when the code page is Korean.  Probably because I have a Chinese IME and no Korean IME.  The font selections is poor.  Character Map doesn't even show Korean Hangul characters for MS Gothic.